# External images not showing on android 'but work on iOS' React Native / React Native Elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have a React Native .63.x project and I'm trying to dynamically set an `Image` uri based on props. The Image element works perfectly on iOS, but doesn't show the image on Android.

```
<Image style={{height: 25, width: 25}} source={{uri: `https://domain/${filepath}`}} />
```

Like I said - I *know* it works because it works for iOS. I'm just not sure if there's a setting or something that I'm missing in order to get the images to show on Android. Another thing - I can set a string and it will work (e.g. 'https://domain/filepath') - but I need to dynamically set it.

How would I inspect the links to make sure they're valid? Is there something I should be doing differently for Android?

Comment: you might log the path or debug with Android studio and go to the `Profile` tab (at the bottom by default) then click network to see the real traffic.

Comment: When I log, the correct file path shows. I'm not sure what the deal is. There *are* query strings attached. Does Android not like query strings in the file path?

Comment: please provide the error showing in Logcat. It should work with url query.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. How would I do that?

Comment: FYR. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler or https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/plugins/network/